# How to change the font-size of QLabel When hovering In Pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

Use the following stylesheet code for Custom Label.  In hover, background-colour: green; and color-white;  works perfectly, but **My problem :** the font-size:27px; and font-weight: 700; will not work as desired. (No change,in font size and as well as font-weight). How to resolve it?

```css
MyLabel[button63="1"]
{
text-align:left; font-size:17px;  font-family: Calibri;
color:black; background-color:rgb(212,185,150); border-style: flat;
}
MyLabel[button63="1"]:hover
{
font-size: 27px; font-weight:700; background-color: green; color: white; 

}
```

**First Program**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal,Qt
import assist_stylesheet_002


class MyLabel(QLabel):
    leftclicked = pyqtSignal()

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.leftclicked.emit()
        QLabel.mousePressEvent(self, ev)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class AssistMain(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle(" Css Style Sheet")
        self.setGeometry(100,100,600,600)

        self.lbl_country = MyLabel("Country")
        self.lbl_country.setProperty("type",'1')
        self.lbl_country.setFixedSize(100,30)
        self.lbl_state = MyLabel("State")
        self.lbl_state.setProperty("type",'1')
        self.lbl_state.setFixedSize(100,30)
        self.lbl_town = MyLabel("Town")
        self.lbl_town.setProperty("type",'1')
        self.lbl_town.setFixedSize(100,30)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.setSpacing(10)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.lbl_country)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.lbl_state)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.lbl_town)
        self.vbox.addStretch()
        # self.setLayout(self.vbox)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = AssistMain()
    qApp.setStyleSheet(assist_stylesheet_002.style_toplayout())
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**CSS Style Sheet**

```
 def style_toplayout():
    return """
    MyLabel[type="1"]
    {
    text-align:left; font-size:17px;  font-family: Calibri;
    color:black; background-color:rgb(212,185,150); border-style: flat;
    }
    MyLabel[type="1"]:hover
    {
    font-size: 27px; font-weight:700; background-color: green; color: white;  
    }
    
    """
```

Comment: The syntax `MyLabel[button63="1"]` indicates that you want to set the attributes for a widget of class `MyLabel` that has property `button63` equal to 1. If you want to refer to the *object name*, you have to use the `#` syntax: `MyLabel#button63 {...}`.

Comment: if I use to like that MyLabel#button63{ text-align:left...........}.  It will not work. I use self.Qwidget.Set Property["button63",'1'] for many Labels. and call css as follows qApp.setStyleSheet(assist_stylesheet_001.style_toplayout()). @musicanabte

Comment: @Kumar please provide a [mre]

Comment: `self.Qwidget.Set Property["button63",'1']` is **not** a valid syntax. As requested (as *usual*), please provide a MRE, ensure you're using a proper syntax, and check if you're not setting any universal stylesheet syntax (eg., without selectors); then remember that changing properties when a stylesheet is already set on a visible widget will **not** change its state for a property based stylesheet attribute (see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types). Also please use valid names for @.

Comment: @musicamante With this user I prefer not to wait for an answer since he is an experienced user and he always falls into the same error: he does not provide an MRE, what do you think? :-)

Comment: @eyllanesc, @ Musicamante... Sorry for Dealy, (  I need to type all things for MRE and also in my area, routine power shutdown time, so this dealy, Extremely sorry)

Comment: @Kumar I think that the font cannot be changed dynamically via QSS since it is observed that the attributes are applied but not the font

Comment: any other way to change it

Comment: @Kumar You must create the MRE before publishing since 1) You avoid closing votes and DV, 2) You save us time in asking you and waiting for the MRE, 3) With an MRE you are more likely to get a faster response.

Comment: ok noted in future we post with MRE

Comment: @Kumar The problem is that you always say the same thing and the next time you do the same. Please use  `@username`

Comment: @eyllanesc, So far I post without MRE is one time only. and this time I think the first MRE code (CSS Code) is enough. but unfortunately, my behaviour hesitates you. Extremely sorry

Comment: @Kumar  An MRE is not a piece of code, put yourself in our position: do you think how many questions we have solved? In many of them the OP provides a piece of code stubbornly pointing out that the error is in those few lines of code so we build a code based on that code and see that it works correctly, then we notify the OP about it and then reflect and provide more code (the MRE) and we realize that the error was elsewhere. Don't you think that causes annoyance?

Comment: @Kumar We would have saved a lot of time and effort if they had given us the code. Do you think that has happened to us with a user? It has happened to us with dozens or hundreds of users

Comment: yes, I realize your problem and feel it . and thank your efforts. @eyllanesc

Comment: @musicamante Thank you and extremely sorry for delay MRE Post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the font cannot be changed dynamically with QSS so a possible solution is to override the enterEvent and leaveEvent methods to change the font using QFont:

```py
class MyLabel(QLabel):
    leftclicked = pyqtSignal()

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.leftclicked.emit()
        QLabel.mousePressEvent(self, ev)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        super().enterEvent(event)
        font = QFont("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(27)
        self.setFont(font)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        super().leaveEvent(event)
        font = QFont("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.setFont(font)
```